# Regex finding comma separated numbers in brackets '[]'?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I need to extract the numbers between brackets. The number of numbers can change.

Example:

```
[2,5,8]
```

or

```
[11]
```

or

```
[3,7,9,12]
```

I need to be able to extract the last number. The problem is, the JSON file is long and contains a lot of numbers and text. These numbers are the only numbers I need and the only ones that are separated by commas, AND without spaces, AND surrounded by brackets.

So far I have tried the regex:

```
info.scan(/(\d,)+(\d?)\]/)
```

which is outputting just the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

To match the last number in square brackets you can use:

```
/\d+(?= *\])/
```

However if input is a JSON string you can use JSON library function `JSON.parse(string)` to grab your desired number.

Comment: What will be the regex to get the content of all strings that are enclosed inside `[]`.. ? I am learning, so asked you.

Comment: That will be: `/\[([^\]]*)\]/`

Comment: @anubhava: With the above exp, it will fetch the numbers just before all the square bracket type ']' But it is not necessary that it should have the starting bracket '['. i.e., if we have '12323,sdasd,89]', it will fetch 89. But, how to make sure that it has a starting square bracket also, then only extract the number.

Comment: If you notice OP mentioned that input is a JSON string and there can be no imbalanced `[ and ]` in a JSON string.

Comment: Ok, I accept. I'm asking you a doubt how to handle such a situation in regex. please help.

Comment: I would do that in 2 steps: (sorry I'm not a Ruby developer). In PHP it would be `preg_replace_callback` where in step 1 you grabe string between `[ and ]` and step 2 you split them by comma.

Comment: @anubhava: Really appreciate your effort. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving JSON, then do the right, and practical, thing, and use the JSON parser to return the data back into an object, then use that object's normal methods for accessing its elements:

```
require 'json'

json_str = '{"array1":[2,5,8],"array2":[11],"array3":[3,7,9,12]}'
foo = JSON[json_str]

foo['array1'] # => [2, 5, 8]
foo['array2'] # => [11]
foo['array3'] # => [3, 7, 9, 12]
```

"Prettified" JSON can be formatted differently than normal JSON output, and that difference can ruin your day if you're trying to use a regular expression. If you use a parser it's a no-brainer:

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate(foo)
# >> {
# >>   "array1": [
# >>     2,
# >>     5,
# >>     8
# >>   ],
# >>   "array2": [
# >>     11
# >>   ],
# >>   "array3": [
# >>     3,
# >>     7,
# >>     9,
# >>     12
# >>   ]
# >> }

puts JSON[JSON.pretty_generate(foo)]
# >> {"array1"=>[2, 5, 8], "array2"=>[11], "array3"=>[3, 7, 9, 12]}
```

It's very similar to using regular expressions to parse HTML and XML. If the JSON is being built by hand, using an algorithm instead of a parser, then the formats can change too; In either case your code stands a high chance of breaking.